# Escape | (vertical bar/pipe) in URL in Wiki Markup Template

Tags: url, escaping, mediawiki, url-encoding, wiki-markup

Is it possible to escape and keep the nonstandard | character as is in an URL in a template Wiki Markup within a table?

```
{| class="wikitable"
|-
! Test in Table
|-
| [http://example.org/{var1}|{var2}|{var3} Example]
|}
```

Should render something like this in the table cell

```
[http://example.org/1|2|3 Example]
```

and link to

```
http://example.org/1|2|3
```

with the vertical bars as is and not encoded like this

```
http://example.org/1%7C2%7C3
```

The 3rd party website requires «|» in the URL, I would fix the URL handling on the server side but that is out of my hands for now.
Any help on a workaround?

I tried these:

```
[http://example.org/1|2|3 Example] doesn't work within a table   
[http://example.org/{var1}&#124;{var2}&#124;{var3} Example] works in tables
```

but both create valid standard URLs where the vertical bar is properly URL encoded as %7C like above which I would like to prevent.

Comment: Do you mean in the code of a template or in a template call? `|` works correctly for me in the code of a template and `%7C` works correctly for me in a template parameter.

Comment: I use it in the code of template, in which case I guess it shouldn't even matter if its a template or not. The final outgoing URL hast to contain the plain | character thats all. Currently the | breaks the parsing of the link.

Comment: missed that, your right this works outside a table yet still gives me the URLencoded strings

Comment: Take a look at [this en-wiki template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:!).  It's commonly used to put "|" character into tables.  Your link will look like `[http://example.org/1{{!}}2{{!}}3 Example]` instead of `[http://example.org/1&#124;2&#124;3 Example]` and still work inside table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

External links, without support from additional extensions, can only be produced by the `[url description]` syntax or a plain URL itself. 
Although as mentioned by skalee, you can use `{{!}}` or other methods to prevent the pipe symbol from being interpreted as part of the Wikitext syntax, the final link will always be encoded.

Without help from extensions, a quick solution would be JavaScript. (If it is on your own MediaWiki site, that would be very simple. `MediaWiki:Common.js` contains JavaScript that will be loaded for all users).

Comment: Thanks, apparently there is currently no way to do this on wikipedia. Anyway the issue has been resolved by switching to more common characters.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the syntax `{{!}}` previously mentioned, it is also possible to escape the vertical bar / pipe using `{{pipe}}` or using `<nowiki>text containing the character | (pipe)</nowiki>`.
Using the HTML entity `&#124;` also works.

Source:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Cite_web#Title

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Table#Rendering_pipe_itself